# If there exists a polynomial of best approximation of degree n, there also exists a polynomial of best approximation of degree n+1.

Tags: analysis, polynomials, approximation

First I'd like to say that although this question was asked before ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7883/there-exist-a-degree-n1-polynomial-of-best-approximation-if-there-exist-a-deg)) and is from the same text, the answer used methods that were not introduced in the text.

Let $P_n(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ and $f:[a,b] \to \Bbb R$ a bounded function.

Define $$\Delta(P_n) = \sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x) -P_n(x)| \ \ \mathrm{and} \ \ E_n(f) =\inf_{P_n} \Delta(P_n),$$ the latter being taken over all polynomials of degree $n$. A polynomial is called a polynomial of best approximation of $f$ if $\Delta(P_n) = E_n(f)$

The previous questions are:

$a)$ show a polynomial of best approximation of degree $0$ exists;

$b)$ among the polynomials $Q_{\lambda}(x)$ of the form $\lambda P_n(x)$, where $P_n$ is a fixed polynomial, there is a polynomial $Q_{\lambda_0}$ such that $$\Delta(Q_{\lambda_0}) = \min_{\lambda \in \Bbb R}\Delta(Q_{\lambda}).$$

The question I am on is:

$c)$ if there exists a polynomial of approximation of degree $n$, there also exists a polynomial of best approximation of degree $n + 1$.

This last part looks like an inductive step which would use $b)$  with $f$ as $f(x) - P_n(x)$ and $Q_{\lambda}$ as  $\lambda x^{n+1},$ $P_n(x)$ being the best approximation. In general, though, the polynomial of degree $n+1$ is not in the form of $P_n(x) + \lambda_0 x^{n+1}.$  Because of this I'm not sure how the question can be done.

Comment: I'm not even sure if the claim is correct. It seems to me that there only exists a best approximation of degree $\le n+1$. I.e. if $f$ is a $1$st degree polynomial, the best approximation of degree $2$ should have the coefficient of $x^2$ equal to $0$, in which case it wouldn't really be of degree $2$.

Comment: @J.J. I also thought of that counter example so we know induction doesn't work. But as I said, the question is set up to use induction so I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @J.J. With that example, there is a polynomial of best approximation of any degree ( I think), but it can't be $\lambda x^2 + ax$ because of what you said.

Comment: @user110503: To be precise, say that $f(x) = x$ on $[0,1]$. Then taking $\frac{1}{m} x^2 + x$ with $m \to \infty$ you find that $E_2(f) = 0$ so that if a best approximation did exist, it would equal $f$ on the entire interval, and in particular it's not of degree $2$.